# Making a AJAX call to a Web Service and pass all the combobox id options as comma separated string

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am new to AJAX and Web Services. Here is what I need help with:
I have a combobox like this

```
<select id="workgroup" class="select-field Required">
<option value="">Select an Option</option>
<option value="ACETestCHAT">Yes</option>
<option value="ACETestCHAT2">No</option>
</select>
```

Here is the sample format of the url that need to pass where the workgroup options should be passed in the url as a comma separated string:

http://abc.xyz.com/tuy/yss?**workgroup=ACETestCHAT,ACETestCHAT2**

The parameters to be picked are in bold above.

Here is the sample JSOn response expected:
{"renewal":5,"status":"success","ACETestCHAT":-1}
The workgroup name will be the key here.

Please reply back in case you need more details.

Any help or pointers are really appreciated!!

Comment: What have you tried ? You can select all the options of #workgroup iterate over them and get the values. Then you can append them to the querystring or pass using data parameter of $.ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and modify its to fit your needs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>http://abc.xyz.com/tuy/yss</div>
        <hr/>
        <select id="workgroup" class="select-field Required">
            <option value="">Select an Option</option>
            <option value="ACETestCHAT">Yes</option>
            <option value="ACETestCHAT2">No</option>
        </select>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/JQuery/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var string = '';
                // Run through each option tag child of select#workgroup
                $('select#workgroup>option').each(function() {
                    if ('' !== $(this).val()) {
                        // Add value attribute of the current option if not empty
                        // Preceding inserted value by comma if not the first value
                        string += ('' === string ? '' : ',') + $(this).val();
                    }
                });
                // Add parameter name and value to the URL only if value isn't empty
                string = 'http://abc.xyz.com/tuy/yss' + ('' === string ? '' : '?workgroup=' + string);
                $('div').text(string);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```